# CLR20r3 DirectoryNotFound in C# windows application Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mscorlib

I have developed a C# windows form application with Visual Studios 2010. it has a couple of external dependencies. It works fine when I run it from VS but fails on start up after I make an installer and try to run it. In the log files created by VS it gives me the following output.So basically there is something wrong with mscorlib.dll; even though I have this dll installed and referenced properly by the project.

```
<ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
    <Parameter0>learningplatform.exe</Parameter0>
    <Parameter1>1.0.0.0</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>515d6cf4</Parameter2>
    <Parameter3>mscorlib</Parameter3>
    <Parameter4>4.0.0.0</Parameter4>
    <Parameter5>50484bd7</Parameter5>
    <Parameter6>3fda</Parameter6>
    <Parameter7>105</Parameter7>
    <Parameter8>System.IO.DirectoryNotFound</Parameter8>
</ProblemSignatures>
```

Note : I am using .Net 4.0 on a 64-Bit Machine but Visual Studios version is 32 Bit(x86 platform).

Comment: No, that problem is located between the keyboard and the chair.  Improve the way you report unhandled exceptions so you can see *why* it went bad like this.  Write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and subscribe it in your Main() method.  Log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  It shows you the Holy Stack Trace.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.I wrote the exception handler and logged the stack trace. so, the problem was that it couldn't find a text file that i use to read some data from at the start up. this text file is located in Resources folder; and after publishing the app, the relative path to it changes.so, I fixed it by changing the path to the text file in my final build before publishing.